# How to replace text between two patterns on different lines?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have several files with text that needs replacing. The text starts and ends with the same pattern each time, but the content in between the patterns is variable. The patterns can appear in the middle of lines, and the content between them often spans multiple lines.

There will only be a single occurrence of the start and end pattern in each file.

I need a command line method to replace the text between the patterns, including the patterns themselves. Outputting to a new file, or editing in place is fine.

A command that operates on a single file will work, as I can loop through the files and apply the command myself. I attempted a `sed` solution but could only manage to replace entire lines.

An example of text would be:

```
Cable Type ID:135, Installation ID:62, Alpha Conductor Origin:
Tolerance Report B74 - 3rd June 1996, Beta Conductor Origin: 
Tolerance Report B74 - 3rd June 1996, Phase Conductor Size: 
45mm, Security: Security-Start Bs86gKI-734Lw#32_nP/5589Zfb8Wj-
sW93j9b Security-End, Location ID:889, Protective Earth Size:
67mm, Protective Earth Max Current (A): 4, Overload Time...
```

The start pattern is `Security-Start` and the end pattern is `Security-End`. I want to replace the patterns and everything in between with the word `REDACTED`.

I would like the output to be:

```
Cable Type ID:135, Installation ID:62, Alpha Conductor Origin:
Tolerance Report B74 - 3rd June 1996, Beta Conductor Origin: 
Tolerance Report B74 - 3rd June 1996, Phase Conductor Size: 
45mm, Security: REDACTED, Location ID:889, Protective Earth Size:
67mm, Protective Earth Max Current (A): 4, Overload Time...
```

Please note that the text between the two patterns may be so long that it spans several lines, it is fairly random in length. This is not clear in the example above

Any language which is available by default on an Ubuntu system will be fine. My first thoughts are 'sed' or 'awk', but whatever you're comfortable with will be fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should work for you:

```
sed -e '/Security-Start/{ N; s/Security-Start.*Security-End/REDACTED/ }'
```

- `/Security-Start/` search for "Security-Start"
- If you found it: "N;" means append the next line.
- and do the replacement`s/Security-Start.*Security-End/REDACTED/` at the final result.

For more than of two line use this one:

```
sed -n '1h; 1!H; ${ g; s/Security-Start.*Security-End/REDACTED/p }'
```

Read [here](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/27/20-Multi-line-sed-search-and-replace/)

Comment: That looks good, there is a possibility that the end pattern may be more than one line away from the start pattern though, which I think would break this. Not obvious by my example, I'll edit to make it more clear.

Comment: @Arronical updated ;)

Comment: That's great, thanks for the link too, explains it all clearly.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it was helpful :-)

Comment: @Arronical To collect all lines a more straight forward approach is to use a loop: `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/start.*stop/FOO/'` (use line breaks instead of `;` for portability)

Comment: @Philippos made my day, his approach with a loop was the key in my script, where the destination file contains multiple-variable lines between the start and stop points.

Answer (score 8):

If the files are not too large, then you could use perl in *slurp mode*:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/Security-Start.*Security-End/REDACTED/s' file 
Cable Type ID:135, Installation ID:62, Alpha Conductor Origin:
Tolerance Report B74 - 3rd June 1996, Beta Conductor Origin: 
Tolerance Report B74 - 3rd June 1996, Phase Conductor Size: 
45mm, Security: REDACTED, Location ID:889, Protective Earth Size:
67mm, Protective Earth Max Current (A): 4, Overload Time...
```

The `-0777` command line parameter effectively unsets the record separator so that the whole file is slurped. The `s` regex modifier causes perl to include newline characters in `.`, making the expression match across lines.

---

Alternatively, with a sed loop:

```
$ sed '/Security-Start/ {:a; $!N; s/Security-Start.*Security-End/REDACTED/; t; ba}' file
Cable Type ID:135, Installation ID:62, Alpha Conductor Origin:
Tolerance Report B74 - 3rd June 1996, Beta Conductor Origin: 
Tolerance Report B74 - 3rd June 1996, Phase Conductor Size: 
45mm, Security: REDACTED, Location ID:889, Protective Earth Size:
67mm, Protective Earth Max Current (A): 4, Overload Time...
```

With GNU sed, you can replace `t; ba` (branch out on successful replacement; (otherwise) branch to `:a`) by `Ta` (branch to `:a` on *un*successful replacement).

Comment: I must get round to learning some perl. There are so many interesting things to learn though!

Comment: I wish to give I could give you 200 upvotes

Answer (score 4):

A more manual approach would be to replace all newline character in the input file with NULLs, use a simple `perl` non-greedy regex to do the replacement and then put the newlines back:

```
$ tr '\n' '\0' < file | 
    perl -pe 's/Security-Start.*?Security-End/Security: REDACTED/g' |
        tr '\0' '\n'
Cable Type ID:135, Installation ID:62, Alpha Conductor Origin:
Tolerance Report B74 - 3rd June 1996, Beta Conductor Origin: 
Tolerance Report B74 - 3rd June 1996, Phase Conductor Size: 
45mm, Security: Security: REDACTED, Location ID:889, Protective Earth Size:
67mm, Protective Earth Max Current (A): 4, Overload Time...
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know about `'\0'` , now a simple `sed` will work too: `tr '\n' '\0' | sed s/Security-Start.*-End?/REDACTED/ | tr '\0' '\n'`

Comment: @Ravexina no, only if there is only one case of `Security-End`, otherwise, because `sed` doesn't support non-greedy matches, it will replace everything from the first `Security-Start` to the last `Security-End`.

Comment: another good point to know ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could do it with awk:

```
awk -v RS='Security-Start.*Security-End' -v ORS= '1;NR==1{printf "REDACTED"}' file
```